# Convert mulitcolumn json to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a json file to a pandas dataframe.

My json's format is:

```
{'n': '{"nbTxs":952,"address":0xaf6787931e7369113b667c2cb09449de88951144,"nbTxsSend":473,"TotalAmountOut":5.649219999999994e-13,"nbConnectedAddressesReceived":15,"nbDistinctAmount":313,"MaxAmountReceived":3.75e-14,"MaxAmountSend":3.1795e-14,"community":222249,"type":Person,"AmountRatio":0.9769629723144068,"nbDistinctAmountSend":278,"MaxAmount":3.75e-14,"nbTxsReceived":479,"nbConnectedAddressesSend":12,"TotalAmountIn":5.782429999999999e-13,"nbConnectedAddresses":25,"nbDistinctAmountReceived":285}',
  's': '{"tx_hash":0x097d22cd626396f9034e6aa3222d34684eea4b0fa755c5f5a21f32910dfd6b75,"value_eth":1.57e-15,"timestamp":2017-07-28 06:57:09 UTC}',
  'i': '{"date":Jun 2017,"address":0x1f573d6fb3f13d689ff844b4ce37794d79a7ff1c,"name":Bancor,"raised":$153,000,000,"type":ICO}'},
 {'n': '{"nbTxs":7298,"address":0xcab007003d241d7e7e8c1092ab93911b669ebd0c,"nbTxsSend":3340,"TotalAmountOut":6.252459000000004e-12,"nbConnectedAddressesReceived":18,"nbDistinctAmount":2243,"MaxAmountReceived":3.033e-14,"MaxAmountSend":3.1996e-14,"community":222249,"type":Person,"AmountRatio":1.0002945308767859,"nbDistinctAmountSend":1629,"MaxAmount":3.1996e-14,"nbTxsReceived":3958,"nbConnectedAddressesSend":6,"TotalAmountIn":6.25061800000001e-12,"nbConnectedAddresses":20,"nbDistinctAmountReceived":1770}',
  's': '{"tx_hash":0x198427cb789f34b14a222bf7a9ed95e52ed545fe6378ee3efcecee845f10f1ce,"value_eth":1.119e-15,"timestamp":2017-08-21 13:50:53 UTC}',
  'i': '{"date":Jun 2017,"address":0x1f573d6fb3f13d689ff844b4ce37794d79a7ff1c,"name":Bancor,"raised":$153,000,000,"type":ICO}'}
```

Using:

```
import pandas as pd 
import json 
from pandas import json_normalize

with open("data/ico.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['n'])
```

I get the TypeError:

> {'n': '{"nbTxs":186,"address":0x6c5208924c5b302f756a79776a8b2918a041ad4d,"nbTxsSend":186,"TotalAmountOut":0.0,"score_behavior":31,"nbDistinctAmount":1,"MaxAmountSend":0.0,"community":9040,"type":Person,"s[...]"score_bulk":10}
> for path n. Must be list or null.

I tried to use the `pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =[...])` function to convert my json into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: That's not JSON to begin with. Even if it's part of a bigger JSON array, it contains serious problems. `'{"nbTxs":952,"address":0xaf6787931e7` is just a string, not a JSON object. Whatever's inside the quotes is treated as just a string. It's not "nested" JSON. Finally, JSON has arrays and dictionaries, not columns

Comment: The error you get is precisely because that's not JSON. If you try to use any online formatter or validator you'll get several errors.